# C Programming: Linear Search with Struct

Tags: c, struct

How do you do a linear search with a struct?

We are given

```
typedef struct {
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
} date;

typedef struct {
    int hour;
    int minute;
} time;

typedef struct {
    char name[SIZE];
    char bloodtype[BLOODTYPESIZE];
} patient;
```

We are then given an input file with names and blood type:

```
Joe_Smith A- 12/13/2010 10:45
Anabell_Brown O+ 10/10/2012 13:10
Regina_White A- 1/13/2008 19:29
```

1
A-

basically we have to do a linear search through the names and blood types and see what matches the A- based on who was added first to the list

I am trying to figure out how to do the linear search based on the names with a space and then the blood type, then another space, and then the time. Any hints would help!
This is probably a simple question but it has been years since I had to code in C.
Thanks!

Comment: The question is not very clear. What does `1 A-` mean in the question? Is it part of the input file? Also, why do you need the structs at all? What does "we are given" mean? Please edit to make the question clearer.

Comment: What have you already tried to do?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more requirements? You said "we are given" a set of typedef declarations and some input. Fro what you've said, you have to load the data into arrays of the appropriate type, then search the arrays.

Given the above typedefs, date[50] would declare an array of 50 date structures, which could then be filled from the input (date.month = month; date.year = year; date.day = day;) and so on for the remaining data. Your linear search is then something like

```
int i = 0;
while ( i < numberOfRecords ) {
    if ( Patient[i].bloodtype == "A-" ) {
     // found a match
   }
}
```